# Is there an explanation as to what the DLCs add with the Talisman Digital Edition?

Tags: expansions, talisman

In short I bought the [Talisman Digital Edition](https://store.steampowered.com/app/247000/Talisman_Digital_Edition/) earlier in the week (oddly reminisced about the game that I hadn't played for 30 years in the morning bought it and the starter pack in the evening).

Have now bought the Season Pass because of a spot Steam Sale.
I added all the downloadable content (DLC) in but found myself a bit lost in terms of what was doing what (e.g. the Dragons and Dark and Light Fate tokens totally threw me).
Have started another game just adding in the base game, Sacred Pool, Frostmarch, City, Dungeon and Reaper expansions & it seems a balanced kind of game.

Is there a preferred amount of DLC to add in (or a preferred set of what to add?) and is there any explanation for what they add to the game (e.g. the Dragon tokens have totally thrown me)?

I am of the impression it's a virtual carbon copy of the board game so I'm figuring it might be appropriate to ask for advice here? (given the subject).

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Edit: asked a similar question on r/Talisman on Reddit and got broadly the answer I was after so as I'm happy enough with the answer below I'll mark this as an answer for closure.

Reddit answer https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/fbktfm/is_there_a_sensible_amount_of_dlc_to_add_in_on/fjaafwl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the rules applicable to all the various mechanics added by a given expansion, your best bet is to start reading [the manual provided by nomad games](https://www.nomadgames.co.uk/talisman-digital-edition-manual-uk). There are sections detailing the mechanics added by each expansion and their rules. This will also include the three released Digital Edition Exclusive expansions, which are not part of the Season Pass. (The Season Pass specifically only includes the physical expansions, the full Runestone card set, and a sizable bunch of extra characters with the notable [and then-controversial] exception of the Shaman character).

If you're looking to see what cards specifically are added by an expansion, you can go to My Collection from the Digital Edition's main menu, select the expansion (or even the base game), then Browse Pack. This will allow you to view all the cards from that expansion, including alternate endings and special cards like The Reaper and The Werewolf.

You can also try looking up information about the physical editions of the expansions themselves, but keep in mind that the following expansions do NOT have a physical version and only exist for the Digital Edition:

- Realm of Souls Expansion (Players become ghosts when killed and interact on a separate plane until they revive or their ghosts gets killed off.)
- Ancient Beasts Expansion (Adds Ancient beasts, some of which can "Apex" triggering an automatic game loss for everyone)
- Clockwork Kingdom Expansion (introduces material cards and the ability to create inventions)

Comment: Thanks. Am going to have a read of all this and I think this may cover off my question. Am keen to just get a better feel for the DLCs as I started playing the base and Starter Expanisons (Sacred Pool, Frostmarch and City) - then added others in and was like what's going on here?